# How to find the array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I tried mongodb,

```
db.getCollection('productList').find({"season": {$elemMatch: {'$gte':2018,'$lte':2020}}, team:"Arsenal"})
```

for above query i got the following result,

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("46ab3e933434234f"),
    "team": "Arsenal",
    "season": [2018, 2020]
},{
    "_id": ObjectId("46ab3e933434234f"),
    "team": "Arsenal",
    "season": [2017, 2018] //I don`t want because of 2017
},{
    "_id": ObjectId("46ab3e933434234f"),
    "team": "Arsenal",
    "season": [2020, 2021] //I don`t want because of 2021
},{
    "_id": ObjectId("46ab3e933434234f"),
    "team": "Arsenal",
    "season": [2018, 2019]
},{
    "_id": ObjectId("46ab3e933434234f"),
    "team": "Arsenal",
    "season": [2019, 2020]
},
```

I want to get the following result,

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("46ab3e933434234f"),
    "team": "Arsenal",
    "season": [2018, 2020]
},{
    "_id": ObjectId("46ab3e933434234f"),
    "team": "Arsenal",
    "season": [2018, 2019]
},{
    "_id": ObjectId("46ab3e933434234f"),
    "team": "Arsenal",
    "season": [2019, 2020]
},
```

I want to get the season between "2018 ~ 2020" only.

Comment: Does all items in `season` array have to be between 2018 - 2020, or at least one should be?

Comment: Did you try without the `$elemMatch` and see what the results are?

Comment: season array have to be between 2018 - 2020 only

Comment: Suppose you have alwasy tow elements in array, u can use https://mongoplayground.net/p/DlNSZkGgXAw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opposite condition with `$not` operator,

- use `$lt` with `$not` for "2018" season
- use `$gt` with `$not` for "2020" season

```
db.getCollection('productList').find({
  $and: [
    { season: { $not: { $lt: 2018 } } },
    { season: { $not: { $gt: 2020 } } },
    { team: "Arsenal" }
  ],
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2qLdC5eIXcf)

---

The second approach using expression aggregation operators,

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `season` and check both conditions it will result in filtered season
- `$size` to get total returned elements from filter
- `$eq` to match both elements size should be the same

```
db.getCollection('productList').find({
  team: "Arsenal",
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$season",
            cond: {
              $and: [
                { $gte: ["$$this", 2018] },
                { $lte: ["$$this", 2020] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      { $size: "$season" }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6qPXd4WJLPa)